# Safe navigation operator for hash with string keys

Tags: ruby, hash, safe-navigation-operator

I have a problem:

```
data = { 'str_key' => ['string1', 'string2'] }

# @param [Hash] data - hash with String key
# @return [boolean]
def some_logic_test?(data)
  data&.<what_to_do_with_string_key?>.include?('string1')
end
```

How can I use the safe navigation operator `&.` for hash with string keys? Keys conversion will by [sic] obligatory?

Comment: Why do you want to use the safe navigation operator in the first place? Could `data` be `nil`? Could `data` not be a hash? Could `'str_key'` be missing? Could `'str_key'` be present and not be an array? What's the actual problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: Your problem is not at all clear.

Comment: Safe navigation seems a bit obtuse here given that a simple `return unless data` guard clause would be perfectly appropriate (and far more readable) in this method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The fact that this key is `String` isn't really relevant here. What you want (well, I guess) is to use safety operator with `[]` method and you can do it like this:

```
data&.[]('str_key')&.include?('string1')
```

You can also make use of [`Hash#dig`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig) method, I think it will improve readability of this code:

```
data&.dig('str_key')&.include?('string1')
```

`Hash#dig` also has the advantage of working properly with nested hashes (it was in fact designed to handle this case):

```
data = { 'str_key' => { 'str_key1' => { 'str_key2' => 'str_value' } } }
data.dig('str_key', 'str_key1', 'str_key2')
# => 'str_value'
```

Comment: So, maybe better in this way:
```data['str_key']&.include?('string1')
```
Which solution will be the best?

Comment: @RadosławSakowicz it depends on the input data, like Stefan mentioned in the comment below your question. If it's possible for `data` to be `nil`, you have to take this possibility into account. Otherwise `data['str_key']&.include?('string1')` is enough, obviously.